# Poisson Distribution Question about the value of $\lambda$

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on a Poisson problem and for the life of me I can't tell what I'm doing wrong, I'm assuming I'm misinterpreting what $\lambda$ is supposed to be. The question reads:

Past insurance company audits have found that 3 percent of dependents claimed on an employee’s health insurance actually are ineligible for health benefits. An auditor examines a random sample of 7 claimed dependents.

What is the probability that all are eligible?

is $\lambda$ supposed to be 0.03 as stated or is the fact that the sample size is 7 changing $\lambda$ to 0.03x7? Or am I missing what $\lambda$ is completely? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: No Poisson here.

Answer (score 1):

Each claimed dependent has probability of $0.97$ of being eligible. Hence, the probability that all $7$ are eligible is just $(0.97)^7$.

Comment: Thank you. the online form mislabeled it as a Poisson problem so I was trying to force myself to use the Poisson distribution formula.